# What is the point of passing a double pointer file as a function argument? Example provided

Tags: c, file, pointers, function-pointers

I understand a pointer to a pointer is the address of another pointer. What exactly is the reasoning behind passing the argument for a file as FILE *(*stream) instead of FILE *stream? If someone could explain to me why it needs to been this way so I can better understand why this works, I would appreciate it. Example code provided below.

```
int SCAN(FILE * ( * stream)) {
  int totalsize = 0;
  int ch = 0;
  //count the number of lines in file
  do {
    ch = fgetc( * stream);
    if (ch == '\n') {
      totalsize++;
    }
  } while (ch != EOF);
  return totalsize;
}
```

Comment: No point, and that formatting is very unusual. Who wrote that?

Comment: In this example there is no actual difference. Usually, a pointer to a pointer will be passed if you want to change the address the pointer is pointing to (for example: if there was a line `*stream = fopen(...);`)

Comment: @Ry- Formatting style is similar to [The One True Brace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and others - not unusual..

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I was referring to `FILE * ( * stream)` and `fgetc( * stream)`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it makes no sense. It is required if you want to modify object referenced by this pointer.

For example:

```
int SCAN(FILE ** stream) {
  int totalsize = 0;
  int ch = 0;
  //count the number of lines in file
  *stream = fopen("myfile", "rt");
  do {
    ch = fgetc( * stream);
    if (ch == '\n') {
      totalsize++;
    }
  } while (ch != EOF);
  return totalsize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the point of passing a double pointer file as a function argument?

It is not needed for `SCAN()`.  `int SCAN(FILE *)` would have been fine.<sup>1</sup>

---

> ... why it needs to been this way so I can better understand why this works, ...

A common usage is not due to the implementation of `SCAN()`, but to retain a common signature style among related functions.

Consider the below.  The others may may use the address of the `FILE *`

```
int SCAN(FILE * ( * stream));
int OPEN(FILE * ( * stream), const char *name);
int CLOSE(FILE * ( * stream));
int THIS(FILE * ( * stream), int foo);
int THAT(FILE * ( * stream), int bar);
```

---

On the other hand, it may have been a late night for the original coder.

---

<sup>1</sup> I would have used a wider return type as file lines can exceed `INT_MAX`.